# Select radio button on text input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

Is there option for radio button to be auto selected when visitor enter text in another input form? I have searched for it, but without success.

I have this form with 3 radio buttons, they allow users to choose size, last radio button is for custom size (width and height). Under last radio button there is text input to input custom height and width.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
   <label for="original-size">Original
       <input type="radio" id="original_size" name="size" value="original" checked="checked">
   </label>
   <label for="medium-size">Medium
        <input type="radio" id="medium-size" name="size" value="medium">
    </label>                   

   <label for="custom-size">Custom
         <input type="radio" id="custom-size" name="size" value="custom">
   </label>

        <input id="custom-width" type="number" name="custom-width" placeholder="Custom width">
         <label for="custom-width">custom width</label>
           and 
          <input id="custom-height" type="number" name="custom-height" placeholder="Custom height">
          <label for="custom-height">custom height</label>
          <br>
          <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

How to select custom-size radio input if user click on custom-width or custom-height text input? Is there option without java script, if not, small code of java script would be fine (I am not using jQuery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to dig up this, is this what you are looking for?

```
<form>
<p>Original: <input type="text"></p>
<p>Medium: <input type="text"></p>

<div id="customWrapper">
  <p>Custom: <input type="radio" id="customSize"></p>
  <p>Custom Width: <input type="text"></p> 
  <p>Custom Height: <input type="text"> </p> 
</div>
</form>
```

```
const div = document.getElementById('customWrapper');

// When the custom width or custom height are clicked on
div.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('customSize').checked = true;   
}, true);

// When clicked somewhere out of the form
div.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('customSize').checked = false;    
}, true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mLvt9ubz/

It basically searches for any input inside the div, when it's event changes then something happens.
In this case the radio button with an ID get's the attribute selected.

Comment: When user click on any input fields for custom size, radio button with id="customSize" is selected, that is fine. But, there is problem, when user click on submit button, somehow "customSize" radio button is unchecked, and it is not sent to server that radio button is checked.Also I tried to wrap submit button inside id="customWrapper", than if user click on "original" or "medium" radio button, on submit it is unchecked and "customSize" is checked. I managed to make it work simply by removing second part of java script "// When clicked somewhere out of the form".

Comment: It would be also nice to have some check if visitor clicked on id="customSize" radio button and clicked on submit button without entering anything in any custom size fields. Right now it is possible to submit form by selecting custom size radio button and without any input into custom size fields. Rarely someone might do that, but it is possible.

Comment: Glad you got it somewhat to work, but regarding PHP stuff I'm not your person.
So you gotta find someone else fo those parts.

Comment: to keep the radio checked (as far as javascript goes, not PHP I think) you can add another event handler like this ```// When the custom width or custom height has a value
div.addEventListener('changed', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('customSize').checked = true;   
}, true);```